# Form building tool for ColdFusion Reactor?

Tags: html, forms, coldfusion, reactor

I'm using Reactor with ColdFusion and I'm wondering if there are any tools that'll build a simple html form automatically from a record object?

Comment: Note: I'm working on a Fusebox app

Answer (score 1):

You might try [Re-Action](http://reaction.riaforge.org/), which is a scaffolding framework for Reactor. It was released in 2007, so I don't know what shape it's in.

Comment: I don't see a link to download and the svn repo appears to be down.

Comment: I sent the developer a email and he said Re-Action is "at least 6 years past dead". =/

Comment: Wow, since it's last update was in 2007, that's not good :). I'd follow Henry's advice and move to CF9's ORM if you can. Far more current.

Comment: I'm not sure what NodeJS has to do with a scaffolding framework for ColdFusion and Reactor :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Model-Glue](http://www.model-glue.com/) scaffolding supports Reactor as well.

Comment: Neat, I want something that will work with Fusebox or any other framework though, can I do so with Model-Glue? b/c I thought it was a mutually exclusive framework.

Comment: You should give MG a try, or switch to using it instead of the legacy Fusebox.  It's good at doing scaffolding if that's the sort thing you're into... Actually, Is reactor still actively being developed and maintained?  Time to use CF9 ORM! :)

Comment: I'd love to switch, lol we're still using svn!! but I don't make the decisions, the CTO does..

Comment: oh well, I'm using SVN still. :) Good luck!